# Non-ascii characters in app target name

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

My apps target name is 美图小报告 but the bundle identifier is set to net.phor._____

I cannot edit the bundle identifier. My app is only for Chinese. How do I set bundle ID correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle ID should not be localized according to [CFBundleIdentifier Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102070):

> The bundle ID string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters. The string should also be in reverse-DNS format.

So Xcode prevents this.

Comment: I was confused because this project is in Chinese, was expecting that "localization" would apply to non-Chinese languages. :-p

Comment: so you want to leave the bundle-identifier as net.nphor._? And not maybe change it to net.nphor.some-name? some-name must not consist of chinese characters of course...

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to your `Info.plist` file and edit the "Bundle identifier". You will notice that right now it contains a part that reads `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. This is the part that you cannot edit in the target inspector, but in the `Info.plist` you can remove that placeholder and provide your own string.

Comment: i never said that that the version-key should be localized!! A bundle-ID of net.npor.----- is just stupid, it should be changed to something like net.nphor.english-app-name .

Comment: s/version-key/bundle-identifier/